# Measure the distance of points from the origin(0,0) - Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I wish to measure the distance of points from the origin(0,0).  Based on this question [Wrong setting of pdist input data - Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69173996/wrong-setting-of-pdist-input-data-matlab)  I used a loop but I wonder is there another way?

Script:

```
clc;
clear all;
x1 = [1:11];
y1 = [1;1;11;16;19;3;14;5;16;10;22];
 
x2 = [0];
y2 = [0];
 
  
for i = 1:length(x1)
    dX = [x1(i),y1(i); x2, y2]
    distResult = pdist(dX,'euclidean')
end
```

Comment: Use [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html). No loop required.

Comment: Tried this and it is a mess, any simpler solution to find the pairwise distances?   x = [flip(rot90(x1)), repmat(0,length(x1),1)];  y = [flip(rot90(x1)), repmat(0,length(y1),1)];   pdist2(x,y,'euclidean')

Comment: Given your point lists as defined above, `pdist2([x2, y2], [x1.', y1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just looking for Euclidean distance with a fixed point like the `(0, 0), you can do it without any explicit loop, like the following:

```
x1 = [1:11].';
y1 = [1;1;11;16;19;3;14;5;16;10;22];
distResults = sqrt(x1.^2 + y1.^2);
```

Moreover, if you desire to find the distance from a fixed point like `(x0, y0)` other than the origin, you can do the following:

```
distResults = sqrt((x1 - x0).^2 + (y1 - y0).^2)
```

If you have concern of different metrics, you can use `pdist2` (as mentioned in comments) like the following:

```
x1 = [1:11].';
y1 = [1;1;11;16;19;3;14;5;16;10;22];
distResults = pdist2([x1 y1], [0,0], 'euclidean');
```

Comment: To generalize it, do `sqrt((x1 - x0).^2 + (y1 - y0).^2)` where `x0, y0` is the starting poiny

Comment: @PranavHosangadi indeed.

Comment: I wish to use pdist as it have more distance metric methods. Maybe I should not used the Euclidean distance  as an example.

Comment: @hsi100 please consider the update.